# mustache template reuse possible?

Tags: jquery, mustache

Please help me in reusing a part of mustache code from one template which should appear in other template.

```
{{#pageone}}
   code here
{{/pageone}}
```

the above code should appear in other mustache template

Answer (score 1):

HAve a look at https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/#partials :

> For example, this template and partial:
>
> base.mustache: `<h2>Names</h2>{{#names}} {{> user}} {{/names}}`
>
> user.mustache: `<strong>{{name}}</strong>`
>
> Can be thought of as a single, expanded template:
>
> `<h2>Names</h2> {{#names}}   <strong>{{name}}</strong> {{/names}}`

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible way to reuse from the template
We can add the code by adding the page required in the current page